# Computer will not boot into OS after installed Graphics Driver

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-10, ubuntu, blank-screen

Here are the computer specs. 
Intel DH67BL, 3.4 ghz i7,
32 GB DDR3 2333 mHz,
750W EVGA PSU,
EVGA GTX 980 Ti Kingpin.

I've been trying to get this graphics card running for a few days, but to no avail. I've tried installing Windows 10, Windows 7, Linux, and every time I install the graphics card driver the computer will no longer boot up into the OS (Shows black/blank screen). I've tried installing an OS, then the motherboard drivers, then graphics, still fails. I've tried different startup options in the BIOS as well as reset the CMOS a couple times. I've also tried different HDD's and a few different OS.

I've noticed that the GPU fans start up on computer start, as well as the CPU, when the 'Black' screen shows up after the Windows7\10\Linux loading icon, the fans turn off on the GPU (CPU fans still running, HDDs still spinning.). I've also noticed that on the GPU only the DVI port will work, DP, HDMI will not work (with generic driver, only one I have been able to get to work).

The only way to recover from this is to start system recovery and restore, or go into safe mode and disable the video card driver and use the generic driver.

Right now I'm working on installing the beta driver (First driver) for the GPU, does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Don't use the beta driver. Your best option would be to use the latest [398.26 WHQL driver](http://www.nvidia.in/Download/driverResults.aspx/135720/en-in). Did this GPU work recently?

Comment: This GPU works in other machines, just not this one. I've tried that driver ~6 times now, keep getting black screen.

Comment: Have you tried other PCIe slots on the motherboard?

Comment: There is only one PCIe slot on the motherboard :(

Comment: If the card works perfectly fine in other machines, I would first assume that the PCIe slot is bad.